# Geny motion credential. I am not able to loggin in geny motion credential

Tags: authentication, virtual, credentials, device, genymotion

I am not able to login in genymotion credential. Can anyone help me in finding a way to login in genymotion credential so that I can download virtual devices?
Or anyone provides me free credentials so that I can try it here on my own machine.

Comment: Can you explain what's happening in detail?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. I just registered, downloaded genymotion, and ran it. When I try to set up a new device, it asks me for username password, but does not accept my (double-checked) correct credentials. Saying "wrong username or password". (Ubuntu 14.04 64bit)

Answer (score 7):

I had faced the same problem. So, Just go to your provided email id's inbox and confirm your account. After confirmation, you are able to log into genymotion.

Comment: I also tried to confirm, but I always got "Could not activate user account: Invalid or expired activation link. Please create your user account again." How the link can be expired if I received it a few seconds ago...

Answer (score 6):

Making sure you've confirmed the account seemed to fix the issue for me.

Comment: Right. I fixed the issue. I went to Genymotion site and tried to sign in there. They sent me confirmation on email. I confirmed. After that i was able to sign in Genymotion app!

Answer (score 3):

Just click the Genymotion settings and **uncheck** http proxy and user authentication.The Second reason may be your password is wrong.It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Genymotion doesn't seem to like email addresses as usernames. Try editing your username - I was experiencing the same problem and that has just worked for me.